# Using compass in IBM Worklight hybrid app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use compass in hybrid app which has environment of iOS, Android and windows.

How to achieve this in IBM MobileFirst Platform?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, Android and Windows Phone you can use the Cordova-supplied Compass API methods. Refer to the Cordova documentation at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_compass_compass.md.html

For Windows Store apps you can use the WinJS API methods. Refer to the WinJS documentation at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sample-sensors-app-windows-8-compass-and-inclinometer-driving-google-street-view-api-using

And google.